# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in form for sending text message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a react public chat app, on trying to send message the following error is shown all the other function are working fine but whenever I try to send message it fails
**my code for chatbox is like this which has the option for sending and reading the text messages**

[image: error while sending]

**my code for chatbox is like this which has the option for sending and reading the text messages**

```
 class Chat extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      user:auth().currentUser,
      chats:[],
      content:'',
      readError: null,
      loadingChats:false,
      writeError:null
    };
    

  }


async componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({readError:null})
  try{
    db.ref("chats").on("value",snapshot =>{
      let chats=[];
      snapshot.forEach((snap)=>{
        chats.push(snap.val());
      })
      this.setState({chats})
    })
  }catch(error){
    this.setState({readError:error.message})
  }
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ content: event.target.value });
}

async handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({writeError:null});
    try{
      await db.ref("chats").push({
        content:this.state.content,
        timestamp:Date.now(),
        uid:this.state.user.uid
      });
      this.setState({content:''})
    }catch(error){
      this.setState({writeError:error.message})
    }
  }





render() {
  return (
    <div>

      <div className="chats">
        {this.state.chats.map(chat => {
          return <p key={chat.timestamp}>{chat.content}</p>
        })}
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input  className="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Text" style={{marginBottom :0 + 'px',marginTop:32 +'rem',marginLeft:10 + 'px',marginRight:20 + "px" , width: 83 +'%',bottom:3,position:'absolute'}}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.content}
            />
            <button className=" btn btn-success" style={{marginTop:10 +'px',position:'absolute',right:3,bottom:3}}>
              Send
            </button>
          </form>
      <div>
        Login in as: <strong>{this.state.user.email}</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
}
export default Chat;
```

Comment: Should you add `()` to your handleChange call?  `this.handleChange()` instead of `this.handleChange`?

Comment: Yeah as we are triggering an event on handleChange, and calling as method and not a function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just bind your method to your class, so basically change your constructor from this:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      user:auth().currentUser,
      chats:[],
      content:'',
      readError: null,
      loadingChats:false,
      writeError:null
    };
  }
```

to this:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      user:auth().currentUser,
      chats:[],
      content:'',
      readError: null,
      loadingChats:false,
      writeError:null
    };
    
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ... actually I binded both handleChange and  handleSubmit  but god knows why I commented them out xd